# How to send an array of objects in JSON format from PHP

Tags: php, json

New to php. I am trying to send JSON data to front end in name-value pair. I tried an example which I got [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)  The following is my code fragment which sends the data in JSON name value format.

```
while($stmt->fetch()){
    $list = array('id' => $fid, 'name' => $fname);
}
$stmt->free_result();
$stmt->close();
echo json_encode($list);
```

I got this on front-end

```
Object {id: 12, name: "Manisha"}
```

The problem is I was expecting an array of objects. The above value is the last value obtained from the SQL query. What are the alterations I should make to this code so that I can get an array of objects. Something like

```
[{"id":"1","name":"Kumari"}, {"id":"2","name":"KM"}, {"id":"3","name":"Manisha"}]
```

Please advice.

Comment: since $list is defined as an array of values, I would have thought you wouldn't get an Object on the front end, but Array [id:12, name:"Manisha"]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

$list needs to be an array, and you can just push items to it like in this code:

```
$list = array();
while($stmt->fetch()){
    $list[] = array('id' => $fid, 'name' => $fname);
}
$stmt->free_result();
$stmt->close();
echo json_encode($list);
```

You could also use the method [fetch_all()](http://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) to get all rows at once, instead of iterating with a loop. Although in this example you'd get all fields that you've selected, instead of just id and name.

```
$list = $stmt->fetch_all();
$stmt->free_result();
$stmt->close();
echo json_encode($list);
```

Answer (score 4):

You should try pushing each object at the end of array like adding to a stack using `array_push` (the equivalent of `$array[] = $data`, but makes it more readable to you).

```
$list=array(); //instantiate the array 
while($stmt->fetch()){
    $data = new stdClass(); // create a new object
    $data->id=$fid;
    $data->name=$fname;
    array_push($list,$data); // push object to stack array
}
$stmt->free_result();
$stmt->close();
echo json_encode($list);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your list array is only storing 1 row. Try this:

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $list[] = array('id' => $fid, 'name' => $fname);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

try creating an array of objects

```
$list = array();
while($stmt->fetch()) {
    // create an object
    $datum=new stdClass();
    $datum->id=$fid;
    $datum->name=$fname;

    $list[] = $datum;
}
$stmt->free_result();
$stmt->close();
echo json_encode($list);
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you:

```
$n = 0;
while($stmt->fetch()){
    $list[$n] = array('id' => $fid, 'name' => $fname);
    $n++;
}
$stmt->free_result();
$stmt->close();
echo json_encode($list);
```

You were overwriting the `$list` multiple times with an array.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose we have this file structure without specific Objects inside :

```
  {
    "Subjects" : []
  }



//Get your Json file and decode it 
$json = file_get_contents('CdStore/Pagetest.json');
$json_data = json_decode($json,true);

   //Specifiy your Objects like this
$NewArray= array( 'Mathematics' => array(),'Physics' => array());
  //Push the new Objects  
array_push($json_data['Pagess'],$NewArray); 
   //Then encode to json
$array = json_encode($json_data); 
  //If you want to get the preview before saving
print_r($array);  

 //Save your file
file_put_contents('CdStore/Pagetest.json', json_encode($json_data));
```

As result you have :

```
 {"Subjects":
     [
       {
        "Mathematics":[],

        "Physics":[]

         }
     ]

  }
```