# Acquire cyrillic data from JSON file in JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

jQuery 3.2.1, Raphael 2.1.1

I have some cyrillic text stored in JSON, e. g.:

```
{
    "regions": [{
            "id": "0",
            "foo": "бар",
        }]
}
```

and I use .getJSON in a .js file to acquire said data:

```
var jq = $.getJSON("http://localhost:8000/data.json",function(objdata){
        for (var i = 0; i < objarr.length; i++)
        {
            $.each(objdata.regions[i],function(key, val){
                objarr[i].data(key, val);
            });
        }
    })
```

I tried `console.log();`-ing various points of data acquisition, and as soon as data is accessed (like `console.log(objdata.regions)` before `for` loop), "бар" is displayed as "���" in the console. Using said data later on shows that this is indeed a problem with data, as the following code

```
objarr[i].mousedown(function(e){
        $infobox.find('.infobox__title').text(this.data("foo"));
    });
```

displays "���" instead of "бар". 
I have the tag `<meta charset="UTF-8">` as the first line after `<head>` in the .html file and I converted the .json file to UTF-8 with Notepad++ just in case. I've read up on using PHP to store data and using `json_encode()` to send it on call, but I definitely need an array of objects, and the small bits of info (SO questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15618873/how-to-send-an-array-of-objects-in-json-format-from-php), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34481541/how-to-parse-json-array-of-objects-in-php); PHP documentation [1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)) I could find don't exactly clear it up.

1. Is there any way to avoid using PHP?
2. If not, how do I parse a JSON file in a PHP file and send it to JS through .getJSON?
3. If this isn't possible either, can you show an example of an array of objects (2-4 objects with 3+ key-value pairs) that's easily readable and ready for PHP use?

Comment: Where does the data come from in the beginning? Is it possible for you to encode it using utf8_encode() in php before sending it to the browser?

Comment: Data is manually entered in a .json file I'm .getJSON-ing data from.

I could try something like
    <?php
    $json = file_get_contents('data.json');
    $json_data = json_decode($json, true);
    utf8_encode($json_data);
    $json = json_encode($json_data, true);
    echo $json

Would that work?

Comment: You should have no problems if json is utf-8, even with german and any kind of alphabet. The issue is something else. Have you tried your code on some other server, somewhere live? Please also make sure your script is utf-8 encoded, too!

Comment: The .json file may not be encoded in utf-8. I'd try the steps you mentioned, but encode it before you use json_decode, while it's still stored as a string.  You could check the encoding of the file using "file -bi data.json" if you're on linux. I'm french and those encoding problems are always pretty frustrating. But usually, you just have to make sure that everything on every layer your data is passed/stored are in the same encoding.

Comment: @skobaljic Huh, I've tried some online hosting and it does work! I suppose something was wrong with the .js file, because all cyrillic text inside it turned out as a mishmash of unicode characters. Thanks!