# Excepton java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, json

I get exception java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 for the below code. But couldn't understand why?

```
String zTab = mNames.get(0);
Toast.makeText(context, zTab, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`
```

JSON

```
{"nazwa":"Rower"},,{"nazwa":"Rower mtb"},{"nazwa":"rower"}
```

Comment: which line does it happen?

Comment: That's telling you `mNames` is empty (size is 0).

Comment: your json is wrong

Comment: Do you know, how I must repair this ?

Comment: json struture is wrong

Comment: post complete json

Comment: with param of the array

Comment: There is PHP script: https://pastebin.com/gZxB6daL

Comment: made it based on what I found on the internet

Comment: oh man. that could also be an issue. NEVER take code unless you fully understand what you are doing. if you CAN NOT talk through your code line y line, then you better not take it without opening a book or watching tutorials to learn more. you will NEVER learn by by stealing code.

Comment: I often take the code from others and if it works, I try to understand what each line does. I know that just taking the code and thinking it into the program thoughtlessly will not do anything

Comment: not sure if I agree with that. the json you posted wasnt valid. the index error is a pretty straight forward error. i dont think you quite understand what you are doing, you just saw code and copy and pasted it.....

Comment: but im not here to make u feel like you cant do it. so take a step back and look at the code. the php file, what does it do? if inside the php file is json, maybe store the json locally (for now) so you can parse it correctly

Comment: You're right. But if it worked, I would start to learn in turn what the given line of code is doing. I do it very often. And just like you, I think that just sticking the code into the program is bad when it comes to learning

Answer (score 2):

The `List` `mNames` doesn't have any items on it. If you call `mNames.size()` it would return `0` or `mNames.isEmpty()` will return `true`.

Make sure you fill your `List` before querying for items inside.

Comment: I have 5 items in List

Comment: Make sure you add items before calling `add`. Can you post the whole code, where the problem is happening?

Comment: if you have five items..show the rest of your code. you are not showing enough

Comment: I downloading tab from PHP script

Comment: I'm doing it for the first time, so I'm sorry for the trivial errors

Comment: can you print out to console each item as you iterate through it? my guess is you thik you are adding something, but they are either null or they dont exist. after after you add(); them, System.out.println(); and see waht gets added. or. use the debugger.

Comment: it did not add up

Comment: My guess would be the JSON parsing is not correct. Make sure you have the correct JSON form and you're parsing it correctly. Take a look at [gson](https://github.com/google/gson).

Comment: When i looking for "rower" in database, PHP script print in web browser this ( [{"nazwa":"Rower"},,{"nazwa":"Rower mtb"},{"nazwa":"rower"}]

Comment: Are you getting any Exceptions?

Comment: No, only IndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: In PHP script is a list. In my opinion, this app does something wrong

Answer (score 1):

```
// in your code
 JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            // make change in this below line

                mNames.add(jsonObject.optString("nazwa"));
            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: then we can help you

Comment: all the name should come in a array

Comment: How I must do this ?

Comment: you selfly working on api or any php developer is working on it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15618873/how-to-send-an-array-of-objects-in-json-format-from-php

Comment: check here how to send json array

Comment: comment the url of your api i check it